# Are there integer systems in hyperbolic plane?

Tags: integers, hyperbolic-geometry

Normally, we can use complex numbers to describe a plane, with their norm related to the Euclidean metric. There are two lattice systems (Gaussian and Eisenstein integers) that permit integers with unique factorizations and such.

My question is: is there an analogue of these systems in hyperbolic plane?

One challenge is that hyperbolic plane doesn't have a consistent set of cardinal directions. If I'd want to build a Gaussian integer analogue based on {5,4} tesselation, the way to get to a particular lattice point would have to be described locally, as a series of turns. It's not obvious how addition would work without global orientation, not to mention multiplication.

Is there a way to transform a hyperbolic tessellation into a consistent 2-dimensional number system?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible and also not sure what you would consider a good system , can you work it out further? But I fear it will not work , also why a {5,4} tessellation I think it is better to use an {even,even} tessellation then you have at least easy straight lines ,but maybe {6,6}{4,8} or {8,4} are even still  easier

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in arithmetic groups as an analogue to the two examples you cite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_group. I make this as a comment because it does not answer your question about addition/multiplication in the sense that you ask. Instead, what it is all about is to express the symmetry group of the tesselation as a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ for which the corresponding matrix entries lie in a certain number field (that, vaguely, is the definition of an arithmetic lattice in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$).

Comment: Maybe interesting http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/contents.html the article : The Eightfold Way: A Mathematical Sculpture by Helaman Ferguson, by William P. Thurston, 1-7:   contains a numbering system for {7,3}

Comment: In my earlier comment I should have written $$PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$$ instead of $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.